# Cannot access list data outside tkinter function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a scenario to get data from user and populate it later for some tasks in Tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

Input_Data = []
# Input_Backup = []

TextEntry = tk.Text(root, height = 15, width = 10)
TextEntry.pack()

confirm_entry = tk.Button(root,text='Confirm Data',\
    width=30,command = lambda :[addbox()])
confirm_entry.pack()

def addbox():
    text_from_Box = TextEntry.get('1.0','end-1c').split("\n")
    numbers = [x for x in text_from_Box]
    global Input_Data
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        Input_Data.append(numbers[i])
    print(Input_Data)
    # global Input_Backup
    # Input_Backup = Input_Data
    return Input_Data

print('My Backup List...',Input_Data)

root.mainloop()
```

But I cannot access it outside function.
It gives:

```
>> My Backup List... []
>> ['2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Kindly Guide me to store it for later use.. I have tried many things but failed..

Comment: Button callbacks cant return anything, use `global`. The only problem you are facing is, move the `print()` after `mainloop()` because code till `mainloop()` just runs once, you updating the list doesnt matter. The code is executed till `mainloop()` and halted there, till you close the window.

Comment: But what if I use the list inside mainloop()..

Comment: You will have to use it inside some other function.

Comment: Actually I will use it for some other functions which i have not included here... Probably that will be inside mainloop().. I have searched a lot but failed..

Comment: I have tried inside functions but failed.. Then Convert my code to non-functioned except for button command..

Comment: If you can help to use it inside some function then I will try that.. But still i get empty list.. Actually getting input from user is critical in this way or entry type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure `addbox` is executed first, after that you can use `Input_Data` anywhere in your code, because its `global`. Here is a simple example with button:

```
def show():
   print(Input_Data) # Do anything with the list

tk.Button(root,text='Print the list',width=30,command=show).pack()
```

After adding this code and clicking this button you will notice the updated list, given that, you have clicked the other button first.